# Utilizar useHistory fora de um componente React

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, router

Boa noite. Preciso criar uma função que importe o useHistory e quando eu chamá-la dentro um componente, ela me permitirá usar o history.push. Mas não está sendo possível utilizar o useHistory fora de um componente React (ao que parece) e estou tendo dificuldades nisso.

O processo final implica na possiblidade de remover o useHistory de cada componente e deixar apenas na função, o que seria o ideal. Mas obviamente, não está funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém teria alguma solução? Meu cenário atual envolve:

"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-router": "5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
"typescript": "4.3.2",
"history": "5.2.0"

Quando chamo o onGoHome em algum evento de click, como num botão por exemplo, ele não faz nada. Coloquei um console.log() para ter certeza que está sendo chamado e está. Mas não executa a mudança de rotas.

Answer (score -3):

Hooks devem ser utilizados apenas no nível de raiz de um componente, ou dentro de outros hooks.

Ou ao menos é isso que a documentação do React sugere.

Isso ocorre porque durante a inicialização do componente, o React registra a ordem em que os hooks foram invocados, e ele utiliza essa ordem para saber o que devolver cada vez que o componente é re-renderizado.

Se um dos hooks for invocado condicionalmente, essa ordem será violada, e o React não irá conseguir devolver os valores corretos a cada chamada.

A constante `history` deveria ser inicializada pelo seu componente, e se necessário, envie esse valor junto com a `url` para a sua função `onGoHome`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta meu amigo. Muitos aqui só clicam no botão de "dislike", mas não ajudam em nada. Infeliz história...mas agradeço seu apoio. Ainda estou tentando encontrar uma maneira de resolver isso.